# How to obtain Google Form titles having their IDs using Apps Script?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I have a script that correctly obtains the list of Drive files from their IDs

My data is on Column A of a Sheet named P12. It is a list of Google Drive files IDs.
It does work for obtaining the title of Google Drive files. However, I can't make it work with the IDs of Google Forms in the view mode (example below), but when I run the script it does not return anything.

[https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/"ID"/viewform](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/%22ID%22/viewform)

```
/** START List of File Names by FileIDs */
function getFileNames() {
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("P12"); // Setup your Sheetname here
const ids = sheet.getRange("A1:a").getValues().flat().filter(String); // Source of the File IDs. A2:a is for Column A, change to suit the column that has your File IDs
const table = [];
for (let id of ids) {
try {
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
var name = file.getName();
table.push([name]);
} catch(e) {
table.push(['']);
}} sheet.getRange(1,4,table.length,table[0].length).setValues(table); } // Target range for File Names will start in Row 2 of Column 4 (D)
/** END List of File Names by FileIDs */
```

I tried changing row 8 to
`var file = DriveApp.getFileById(form.getId());`

Comment: Hi @Felipe S, forms do not work as sheets or other files, if you do not have edit access, you wont be able to access any information through App Script.

Comment: I get it. But I do have edit access. However I would like to use this script to make sure that the forms sent to data collection team are accurate. Would there be a workaround?

Comment: I see the URL you provided on your post is the VIEW URL of the form.  In order for the script to work properly, you need to provide the FORM ID that you get when accessing the form on EDIT mode. That URL looks like this:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/"ID"/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on my comment, you cannot access a form thrugh App script using the View mode ID. However, if you track the IDs when accessing the forms on EDIT mode then you can maybe track the ids in the following way:

```
/** START List of File Names by FileIDs */
function getFileNames() {
 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("P12"); // Setup your Sheetname here
 const ids = sheet.getRange("A1:a").getValues().flat().filter(String); // Source of the File IDs. A2:a is for Column A, change to suit the column that has your File IDs
 const table = [];
 for (let id of ids) {
  try {
   var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
   var name = file.getName();
   var mimeType = file.getMimeType();

   if (mimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.form") {
    
    var tempForm = FormApp.openById(id);
    var publishedUrl = tempForm.getPublishedUrl();

    table.push([`FORM  - ${name} / URL ${publishedUrl}`]);
    
   } else {

     table.push([name]);

   }
  
  } catch (e) {
  
   table.push(['']);
  }
 } sheet.getRange(1, 4, table.length, table[0].length).setValues(table);
} // Target range for File Names will start in Row 2 of Column 4 (D)
/** END List of File Names by FileIDs */
```

Comment: that's a nice solution, tks